# subpace topology with closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y\subset X$ a subset. Then the subspace topology on Y is defined to be the collection, $\{Y\cap U\}$ where $U$ is open in $X$. Is this collection also equal to the collection, $\{Y\cap C\}$ with $C$ a closed set in $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely not. If you consider $(0,1)$ as  a subspace of $\mathbb R$ then $(0,1) \cap ([\frac 1 3, \frac 3 4])$ is not open on $(0,1)$.

However it is true that closed sets in $Y$ are precisely those of the type $Y \cap C$ where $C$ is closed in $X$.